# How can I get the duration (in seconds) of a time from a custom Moment format

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I'm trying to get the duration of a time in seconds, however that time is represented as a custom format.

I'm doing the following:

```
moment.duration(inputTime, "HH:mm:ss.SSS").asSeconds()
```

Which works, however I fall into problems when using the typescript definitions for moment:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

as I get the following typescript error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"HH:mm:ss.SSS"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"s" | "m" | "h" | "d" | "M" | "y" | "year" | "years" | "month" | "months" | "week" | "weeks" | "w...'.
```

How can I work around this? If I don't use the typescript definitions, the line works as expected.

I'm using moment version 2.22.1

Comment: Can you create a working/runnable demo of your code? That would be easy to debug

Comment: What is the value of `inputTime`? See [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) docs `"HH:mm:ss.SSS"` is not a valid parameter

Comment: @VincenzoC input time is: `00:40:01.884`, which gets resolved to `2401.884`. I would like to keep the milliseconds actually, so the output format should be seconds plus milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, seemingly not specifying that second parameter at all still gives me the same (correct) result, so i'll use that :)

```
moment.duration(inputTime).asSeconds()
```